Using Vue JS 3, vitest and happy-dom, how do I mount a component that requires an HTMLElement's clientWidth?
We have a component that does the following:

Inside the template, has a div referred to as workspace
when the component is mounted, inside the onMounted() it calls a method to calculate size
the calculation method checks the workspace div's clientWidth and clientHeight

The code simplified, looks something like this:
<template>
  <section>

    ...

    <div 
      ref="workspace"
      style="height: 100%"
    >

       ...

    </div>

    ...

  </section>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
  ...
  
  const workspace: Ref<HTMLElement | null> = ref(null)
  
  ...

  onMounted(){
    ...
    
    calculateCanvasSize
    
    ...
  }
  
  ...

  const calculateCanvasSize = () => {
        // Minimum space available
        canvasSize.value = Math.min(
            workspace.value!.clientWidth,
            workspace.value!.clientHeight,
        )
    }

</script>

For testing, we use vitest, happy-dom, andvue-test-utils. Our vite.config.mts looks like this:
 // Vitest config
        test: {
            environment: 'happy-dom',
            coverage: {
                provider: 'istanbul',
                reporter: ['lcov', 'html'],
            },
            exclude: [
                '**/node_modules/**',
                '**/dist/**',
                '**/cypress/**',
                '**/.{idea,git,cache,output,temp}/**',
                '**/{karma,rollup,webpack,vite,vitest,jest,ava,babel,nyc,cypress,tsup,build}.config.*',
                '**/coverage/**',
            ],
            reporters: ['vitest-sonar-reporter', 'default'],
            outputFile: {
                'vitest-sonar-reporter': 'test-report.xml',
            },
            globals: true,
            setupFiles: ['test/GlobalOptions.ts'],
        },

        //Add env variables
        define: {
            'process.env': env,
        },

I can't write a basic unit test as the test is unable to mount the component. It throws the following error saying it is unable to get the clientWidth of the workspace div
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'clientWidth')

To debug, in the test I do the following:
   document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="test" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>'
   document.body.style.width = '100%'
   document.body.style.height = '100%'
   document.body.configurable = true

I noticed that the document.body size is always 0, even though I add a div that has styled width and height and I add css styling to the document.body directly.
Console logging as many useful variables as possible, I get the following info:
document.body.innerHTML <div id="test" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
document.body.outerHTML <body style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"><div id="test" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div></body>
document.outerHTML undefined
global.innerWidth 1024
global.innerHeight 768
global.clientWidth undefined
global.clientHeight undefined
global.window.clientWidth undefined
global.window.clientHeight undefined
window.clientWidth undefined
window.clientHeight undefined
window.innerWidth 1024
window.innerHeight 768
document.featurePolicy undefined
document.implementation DOMImplementation {}
document.visibilityState visible
document.compatMode undefined
document.body.clientWidth 0
document.body.clientHeight 0
document.body.innerWidth undefined
document.body.innerHeight undefined
document.body.style.width 100%
document.body.style.height 4
screen Screen {
  width: 1024,
  height: 768,
  availWidth: 1024,
  availHeight: 768,
  colorDepth: 24,
  pixelDepth: 24
}

My question: Which of the following am I going to need to do to be able to write a test where the component mounts successfully?

Leave the component as it is written and find a different way to set the required clientWidth and clientHeight required to mount the component?
Leave the component as it is written but change out the test framework/structure/tools to be able to set the required clientWidth and clientHeight required to mount the component?
Re-write the component such that using the already existing framework is able to mount the component successfully for unit tests.


It ends up it was an error on my part, the workspace div had a v-if statement that was causing it not to render (be null), which was causing the error I was seeing.
Once that was fixed, the component was able to mount, and I could write unit tests.
To answer my originally posted question: Yes you are able to use the existing test framework AND the implementation of the component DOES NOT need to change.
